# Using CUDA in ROS with eee PC 1215N

Tags: ros, turtlebot, cuda, bumblebee

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I know that with bumblebee/ironhide, I can use the Ion 2 graphics card on linux, but after installing bumblebee or ironhead, can I use CUDA and turtlebot? Has someone tried it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11991/using-cuda-in-ros-with-eee-pc-1215n/) by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2011-11-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2011-11-19**:
What about turtlebot? Have you tried to use virtualGL with turtlebot?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-01-05**:
The 1215n is the turtlebot laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got glx working for the nvidia gpu through virtualGL:  http://answers.ros.org/question/2258/how-to-make-use-of-the-nvidia-gpu-on-asus-1215n  though I have not tried to compile cuda on it yet.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0